# Can this "syntax sweetener" be improved?

Tags: lua

I have a Lua project that uses some syntax sugar described in [DecoratorsAndDocstrings](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DecoratorsAndDocstrings), near the bottom of the page. It looks like this:

```lua
random =
  docstring[[Compute random number.]] ..
  function(n)
    return math.random(n)
  end
```

Notice how the function definition is concatenated to the result of the function previous function call. I also have similar sugar like this:

```lua
something = foo.bar "Blah" { a = 1, b = 2 }
```

Basically, the idea is that instead of `foo.bar` taking two arguments (a string and a table), it only takes the first argument, and returns a function that finishes the operation (like a continuation). In the first example, instead of returning a function, we'd return a table with a `__concat` meta method.

I ended up with a handful of functions in my project that use syntax like this. The problem is:

- The code is not straightforward.
- It's difficult to document properly.
- Adding support for non-sugared calls compounds the previous two problems.

So, I had the idea to just write them as normal functions, and create a "sweeten" function that takes two arguments: a function to "sweeten," and the number of args it wants. It returns a wrapper for the function. If you call the wrapper with at least the required number of arguments, it will simply tail-call the wrapped function. If you call it with less arguments, it will instead return a sort of "continuation table" with both `__call` and `__concat` metamethods set up as wrappers to the wrapper -- calling them will invoke the wrapper again with the previous args and the new args.

```lua
local function sweeten(fn, argc)
  local wrapper

  argc = tonumber(argc) or 2

  local function unpack_plus(t, i, ...)
    i = i or 1
    if i <= #t then
      return t[i], unpack_plus(t, i + 1, ...)
    else
      return ...
    end
  end

  local function resume(t, ...)
    return wrapper(unpack_plus(t, 1, ...))
  end

  local meta = { __call = resume, __concat = resume }

  wrapper = function(...)
    if select('#', ...) >= argc then
      return fn(...)
    else
      return setmetatable({...}, meta)
    end
  end

  return wrapper
end
```

To test if out, you can do something like:

```lua
function foo(a, b, c) print(a, b, c) end
function sweet_foo = sweeten(foo, 3)
sweet_foo "qwe" "asd" "zxc" -- prints stuff
```

I feel like I should be able to simplify `sweeten` and still get the same result. I'd especially like to get rid of `unpack_plus`, but I can't see a way to do it. Any thoughts?